# How to add MySQL Databases & Users from form to config file

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form in install/install.php :

```
<form method="POST" action="installing.php" onSubmit="return validatedb();" id="installform">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="initem">
            <div class="dib name">Database Host</div>
            <div class="dib value"><input type="text" name="dbhost" value="<?= $preDbHost ?>" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="initem">
            <div class="dib name">Database Name</div>
            <div class="dib value"><input type="text" name="dbname" value="<?= $preDbName ?>" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="initem">
            <div class="dib name">Database User</div>
            <div class="dib value"><input type="text" name="dbuser" value="<?= $preDbUser ?>" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="initem">
            <div class="dib name">Database Pass</div>
            <div class="dib value"><input type="text" name="dbpass" value="<?= $preDbPass ?>" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stepper bbr">
        <div class="fll">Step 1/2 : Database Settings</div>
        <div class="flr"><input type="submit" value="Validate & Continue" class="btl bbr"/></div>
        <div class="cls"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in inc/config.inc.php this code:

```
<?php

    // Error Reporting
    @error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


    /// Database Settings ///
    define('DB_NAME', '');          // MySQL database name
    define('DB_USER', '');          // MySQL database user
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');      // MySQL database password
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');     // MySQL database host name (in most cases, it's localhost)


    if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
        $userid = (int)$_SESSION['userid'];
    }

    define('Jobfia_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    define('Jobfia_PAGE', TRUE);

    require_once(Jobfia_ROOT."db.inc.php");
    require_once(Jobfia_ROOT."functions.inc.php");

    if (!defined('is_Setup'))
    {
        require_once(Jobfia_ROOT."siteconfig.inc.php");
    }

?>
```

How to add by php the form values in inc/config.inc.php at Database Settings and in the same time to verify if they are real values or not?

Comment: i think you need functions like fwrite, file_put_contents to write data in the file. http://in2.php.net/file_put_contents , http://in3.php.net/fwrite

Comment: and after that how to verify if the database info are correct ?

Comment: if you are using mysqli, you can do like,  `$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));` http://in3.php.net/mysqli_connect

Comment: http://in3.php.net/mysqli_connect note,values of constants are assigned if values posted are correct without error, else throw error and re-show form.

Answer (score 0):

Import the file  inc/config.inc.php  In file install/install.php
than

```
$DB_NAME
$DB_USER
$DB_PASSWORD
$DB_HOST
```

Can be access Directly

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

Option 1 - keep a db.inc.php which you will overwrite whenever the form is saved.
and call it in the config.inc.php like this:

```
// Error Reporting
@error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


/// Database Settings ///
require_once('db.inc.php')



if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    $userid = (int)$_SESSION['userid'];
}

...
...
```